# Material UI / Webpack / React - the className optimization/minification in production mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui, production

```
webpack - v4+
material ui - v4.9.6
react - v16.12.0
```

In a normal way all classes should be as the last one from the first example. In some reason on production mode, many of the classes do not change. Any idea?

Example 1:

```
<div class="MuiDrawer-root MuiDrawer-docked jss408"></div>
```

Example 2:

```
<div class="MuiPaper-root jss469 MuiPaper-elevation1 MuiPaper-rounded"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

styles `className` is not designed as deterministic in prod mode.

**But** the generated class names of the `@material-ui/core` components behave differently. When the following conditions are met, the class names are deterministic:

- Only one theme provider is used (No theme nesting)
- The style sheet has a name that starts with Mui (all Material-UI components).
- The disableGlobal option of the class name generator is false (the default).

---

Refer:

- Document of Material-UI [className generation](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#class-names)
- API of the generator [creategenerateclassname](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#creategenerateclassname-options-class-name-generator)

Comment: Thanks. This solved the issue:
const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({ disableGlobal: true }) and 
<StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}> .... </StylesProvider>