# How to minify Material UI class names (v5)?

Tags: material-ui

Still not sure how to correctly minify the the default Material UI classnames (for example `MuiList-root MuiList-padding`) for production builds.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import StyledEngineProvider from '@material-ui/core/StyledEngineProvider';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import { ThemeProvider, StylesProvider, createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
    productionPrefix: 'foobar',
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <App />
            </ThemeProvider>
        </StylesProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>,
    document.querySelector('#root'),
);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60817296/863110 (Means, it shouldn't be minified because `Mui-..` class names should be deterministic).

Comment: When I have a look at Shutterstock, they have shorten all Mui class names. No idea how this works.

Comment: How do you know they are using material-ui?

Comment: Okay, Shutterstock uses react-toolbox (material design components) for the website. Material UI lists Shutterstock on the main site (but perhaps only for the iOS app or so).